# Mechanism of UDP communication between PC and iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, tcp, udp

I am trying to create a test app to open up UDP connection between a PC and iPhone.

As far as i know,

For UDP, 2 PC's can communicate with each other via each other's IP address and a port number.

How can this be done between a PC and iPhone?

I understand iPhone has its own ip address just like a PC, but what about a port number to listen to/ send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSStream to implement UDP socket communication.

Use this code for establishing a socket connection:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;

- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
}
```

This tutorial will help you :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost is for TCP, not UDP

Answer (score 1):

iOS has the same BSD (POSIX), CoreFoundation, and Foundation network APIs as macOS. You just do it the same way as when communication between two Macs.

Just as on any computer, you can open any UDP port on an iPhone that is above 1024 (ports below can only be opened by system processes, same on macOS), as long as that port is not already in use by another process, and then you receive packets being sent to this port number.

The following example code works equally on an iPhone as it works on a Mac as it works on a Linux or BSD PC:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/

It will not work on Windows, as Microsoft prefers to always do everything in a different and incompatible way than the rest of the universe.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access to an iPhone port, so if you are thinking of running kind of service in the phone just forget it. This is a restriction from the network cells.